# The Method used in the solution

Tags: divergent-series

$$ \sum_{k=1}^∞  \frac{(x^k)} {(k^2)} 
$$
The question is, Check if it is divergent.
Solution:
Step1:
$$ R_1 = \frac{1}{lim \frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2}} =1
$$
can someone explain step 1.Which method is used to solve it? Is it cauchy?

Comment: It seems to be you're using some kind of D'Alembert's (ratio's) test: for a power series as yours, the convergence radius $\;R\;$ is given by $$\frac1R=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\; $$and in your case with $\;a_k=\frac1{k^2}\;$  ...

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks got it